# How to display mb/s instead of b/s in progressbar and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, progress-bar, transfer

I am trying to change the way progressbar (version 2) displays the transferred/total file size in Python 3. Here's the code:

```
import progressbar
import requests

url = 'http://download.openbricks.org/sample/H264/big_buck_bunny_1080p_H264_AAC_25fps_7200K_short.MP4'

request = requests.get(url, stream=True)

file         = open('test.mp4', 'wb')
file_size    = int(request.headers['Content-Length'])
file_size_mb = round(file_size / 1024 / 1024,2)

chunk_sz = 512

widgets = [progressbar.Bar(marker="#",left="[",right="]"),
           progressbar.Percentage()," | ",
           progressbar.FileTransferSpeed()," | ",
           progressbar.SimpleProgress()," | ",
           progressbar.ETA()]

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=file_size).start()

i = 0

for chunk in request.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_sz):
    file.write(chunk)
    i += len(chunk)
    bar.update(i)

bar.finish()
print('File size: {0} MB'.format(file_size_mb))

file.close()
```

The output:

> [#########################] 91% | 741.3 KiB/s | 3397632 of 3714474 | Time: 00:00:08
>
> File size: 3.54 MB

I want to be able to make the "**3397632** of **3714474**" be displayed in the MB format (like in the *file_size_mb* variable), not in Bytes as it is being displayed by progressbar by default.

I've read the docs in [Progress Bar’s documentation](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I couldn't find the answer to my question in any of the examples given there.

Comment: did you try to simply pass `file_size_mb` to the ProgressBar constructor instead of `file_size`?

Comment: you could also see the DataSize widget: http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.DataSize

Comment: I tried it, yes. It doesn't work though. The bar thinks it has to download that in bytes still so, it quickly fills up up to 100%.

About the DataSize widget, I read about it in the link provided by you however I don't think I quite understood it. Maybe because I'm relatively new to Python or even programming but, could I trouble you to elaborate on an example for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obtain this kind of display relatively easily with [DataSize](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.DataSize) widget:

```
[######                                 ] 17% | 256.0 KiB/s | 631.0 KiB /   3.5 MiB | ETA: 0:00:11
```

you can do this by replacing the [SimpleProgress](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.SimpleProgress) widgets by two [DataSize](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.DataSize) widgets, as shown below:

```
widgets = [progressbar.Bar(marker="#",left="[",right="]"),
           progressbar.Percentage(), " | ",
           progressbar.FileTransferSpeed(), " | ",
           progressbar.DataSize(), " / ",
           progressbar.DataSize(variable="max_value"), " | ",
           progressbar.ETA()]
```

By default, the [DataSize](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.DataSize) widget displays the current value, but you can specify that you want it to display the max value by passing it "max_value" as *variable* parameter.

The problem is that it is not documented and you have to inspect the code to find this information. So this could be changed one day and no more work with a later version of the module.

Considering [the DataSize doc](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.DataSize), it seems you can alter the default format by passing a custom value to *format* parameter. The default format is

```
format='%(scaled)5.1f %(prefix)s%(unit)s'
```

I think you could get two decimal numbers by specifying this format:

```
format='%(scaled)5.2f %(prefix)s%(unit)s'
```

Concerning the displayed unit, the doc mentions the prefixes parameter which defaults to

```
prefixes=('', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi', 'Yi')
```

You could probably pass another tuple with the prefixes you want. But consider this [article discussing about binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) before doing that. If you use powers of 1024 to convert your units, and if you want to be exact, then you probably wants to use the IEC binary prefixes with the "i" character.

---

An other, but longer, way to achieve what you want would be to derive the [SimpleProgress](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progressbar.widgets.html#progressbar.widgets.SimpleProgress) class to make one which fits you needs.

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna try it when I get home from work! Thanks again!

Comment: P.S Do you think I could make it display 2 decimals instead of only 1? As in 3.54 MiB (Which is the actual size of the file in the example). And what about the "MiB" nomenclature? Shouldn't it be "MB" instead?

Comment: @user349326 answer edited to respond to fit your additional questions

Answer (score 0):

From `progressbar` documentation :

```
class progressbar.widgets.SimpleProgress(format=’%(value)d of %(max_value)d’,
max_width=None, **kwargs)

Bases: progressbar.widgets.FormatWidgetMixin, progressbar.widgets.WidgetBase

Returns progress as a count of the total (e.g.: “5 of 47”)
```

So I'd assume you can use the `format` parameter to do what you need.

```
widgets = [progressbar.Bar(marker="#",left="[",right="]"),
           progressbar.Percentage()," | ",
           progressbar.FileTransferSpeed()," | ",
           progressbar.SimpleProgress(format='%(value/1024/1024)d of %(max_value/1024/1024)d')," | ",
           progressbar.ETA()]
```

Another way would consist in getting getting the output from simpleProgress, parse it to get the values, and do the maths manually.

Comment: Sadly, you cannot. That's what confused me a lot in the first place. Here's the output when I try to do it as instructed: http://pastebin.com/HbiqVYeL (The error is pretty big so I won't be pasting it here.

For the second suggestion however, I don't know how I'd do that. I mean, how would I insert the information back on the widgets list or use it to update the bar?

Sorry if I look like a rookie in Python but, that's exactly what I am. I've been studying by myself for 3 months now. Thanks for your help though. I really appreciate it.